# How to rename items inside a column on R?

Tags: r, dataframe

How to rename items in column L1 i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 on R? to A,B,C,D,E,F,G,

```
          logFC variable value L1
17   0.6629950   geneID  ftsE  1
39   1.1672554   geneID  ftsE  2
61  -0.3932697   geneID  ftsE  3
86  -3.1872927   geneID  ftsE  4
110  0.3439427   geneID  ftsE  5
134  0.1188008   geneID  ftsE  6
159 -0.2550425   geneID  ftsE  7
```

Comment: `df$L1 <- LETTERS[df$L1]`?

Answer (score 1):

As Rui Barradas mentioned, you can use LETTERS

```
df$L1_new <- LETTERS[df$L1]
```

LETTERS has A:Z indexed 1:26

Comment: Is it possible to rename the items instead to say
1 to strain  1; 2 to strain 2 and so on. How to I connect them to the dataframe too. I`m new on R, its a little confusing for me sorry :)

Comment: no problem.  use  :   paste0("strain ",LETTERS[df$L1])

Comment: @user13480343 you wrote, *Is it possible to rename the items instead to say 1 to strain 1; 2 to strain 2 and so on. How to I connect them to the dataframe too.* - might you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62265271/edit) your original question and clarify it by adding your detailed requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an equivalencies table and then join to the original data, if you'd like to preserve the original name (using dplyr):

```
df.equivalencies<-data.frame(L1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 
newname=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"))

yourdataframe%>%left_join(df.equivalencies)
```

or use factors if you'd rather replace original data (base R):

```
yourdataframe$L1<- factor(yourdataframe$L1, 
levels=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 
labels=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"))
```